# Regarding Rails Application Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to deploy my rails application. I have a small requirement here.

I am not using Devise. I am providing user to login via his username and password. But now I also want to provide user to login via his email too.

How can I make this work. It should work for username and also for email.

My access controller login action is like this:

```
  def attempt_login
    if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
      p 'Fields Check'
      found_user = User.where(:username => params[:username]).first
      p "#{@found_user.inspect}"
      if found_user
        authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      end
    end
    p "#{authorized_user.inspect}"
    if authorized_user
      if authorized_user.email_confirmed
        # mark user as logged in
        session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
        session[:username] = authorized_user.username
        redirect_to(:controller => 'users',:action => 'index')
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Please activate your account by following the
        instructions in the account confirmation email you received to proceed'
        redirect_to(:controller => 'home',:action => 'index')
      end
    else
      p "Not a Registered User"
      flash[:error] = "Invalid username/password combination."
      redirect_to(:controller => 'home',:action => 'index')
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You might want to consider using the gem sorcery- https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery. Its a light weight authentication library which gives you more control than devise does. There are some good resources online to implement its different features and it works well with pundit, a gem for handling authorisation.

Comment: I dont want to use other gems like devise ! I need a way to make this work without them  ! I saw some blogs where this can be done in devise by creating a variable login which can include both username and email ! I want to implement this in that way ! So trying to get some help from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the initial check as follows

`if (params[:username].present? || params[:email].present?) && params[:password].present?`

and then the query to find the user

`User.where('username= ? OR email= ?', params[:username], params[:email]).first`

Comment: But in Login page ! I gave :username as textfield in my view ! Then how will that work ?

Comment: That's even easier, leave the **if** as is, and change the query to: 

User.where('username= ? OR email= ?', params[:username], params[:username]).first

Comment: Oh great will try it out ! :)

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm!